# Separate permission required for amicus curiae brief?

Tags: process

I submitted an amicus curiae brief to a federal case and it was rejected on the grounds I had no permission from the court to submit one, however, in the brief itself, at the beginning I specifically asked for permission to submit the brief.

Does the permission have to be asked for in a separate filing?

I don't see why I can't ask for permission within the brief itself.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the court.  For example, at the appellate level in the United States Federal Courts, you would need to file a motion, not a brief.

The motion would have to request permission from the court to file the brief.  A *proposed brief* would have to be filed with the motion, but would not be the same document.

> (a) When Permitted. The United States or its officer or agency or a
>   state may file an amicus-curiae brief without the consent of the
>   parties or leave of court. Any other amicus curiae may file a brief
>   only by leave of court or if the brief states that all parties have
>   consented to its filing.
>
> (b) Motion for Leave to File. The motion must be accompanied by the
>   proposed brief and state:
>
> (1) the movant's interest; and
>
> (2) the reason why an amicus brief is desirable and why the matters
>   asserted are relevant to the disposition of the case.
>   ...

https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frap/rule_29

Comment: What about your constitutional right to petition for a redress of grievances? Im not sure, but I think I remember reading that the Supreme Court at some point rule that amicus briefs are a form of first amendment expression.

Comment: Cite the case.  The Eleventh Circuit is even more restrictive than the FRAP.  Also, grievances against *you* can be petitioned against--to Congress, or I suppose to the courts if you have standing.  Actually, you did petition, they just didn't respond--which they don't have to do.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_petition_in_the_United_States